# Accessing (not changing) Renderer AA state after scene instantiation

Tags: debugging, mobile, three.js, antialiasing, renderer

For debugging purposes, I'd like to know the current state of AA in a given scene (typically on mobile), but that property doesn't seem to be persisted in any way on the renderer object after instantiation. It's nontrivial to get that information from the code itself because A-Frame takes over AA settings under certain conditions that are challenging to pinpoint.

If there's no way to assert the state of AA in realtime, can I glean that information through DevicePixelRatio? For example, if renderer.getPixelRatio() returns 2, does that mean AA is on, and so forth?

(Currently testing this in chrome's iOS emulation, which I know is not ideal.)

Comment: I'm completely confused by this question. I thought that AA can only be on or off with WebGL, and that the browser determines what sort of quality it would be but i may be completely wrong. `For example, if renderer.getPixelRatio() returns 2, does that mean AA is on, and so forth?` these two should be completely unrelated.

Comment: three lets you pass an "antialias" bool in the renderer parameters - see https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer. The fact some platforms default to certain behaviors is exactly why I'm trying to inspect that after instantiation. And you may be right that devicepixelratio is unrelated - not sure myself.

Comment: ahhh, you want to know what AA actually does? This wont be on the webgl level i think, it's up to the browser to figure out what to do and how many passes to do.

Comment: For now, I wouldn't mind just finding out if on the threejs level the param was passed as true or false. A-Frame hijacks some instantiation params and I don't trust declarative param passing a-la <a-scene antialias="true"> because I've seen similar prop passing break quite frequently under certain conditions.

Comment: From the docs it doesn't look like there is, no `getParams` method.